# Binary search not working when looping on the same table

Tags: abap, binary-search

I'm making a function that exports a table with some data T_DATA[].
There is a part when I loop through an internal table( T_ENTRIES[]) and use binary search on the T_DATA[].
Before the Loop, T_DATA[] is sorted by the key I use in the read statement.
For some reason, the read fails a lot of time even if it has same key in both tables.

If i remove the binary search it works well.

Is this a common problem with tables that declared as exporting in the function?

Because when I move the table (T_DATA[]) to a different internal table and use the binary search on it, it works fine.

Thank you!

```
SORT t_patient_list[] BY kunnr.

LOOP AT lt_cov_entry[] ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_cov_entry>).

  READ TABLE t_patient_list[]
  ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_patient_list>)
  WITH KEY  kunnr = <ls_cov_entry>-kunnr.
  BINARY SEARCH.

  IF sy-subrc <> 0.
    CLEAR ls_patient_record.
    MOVE-CORRESPONDING <ls_cov_entry> TO ls_patient_record.
    APPEND ls_patient_record TO t_patient_list[].
  ELSE.
    <fs_patient_list>-hosp_type = <ls_cov_entry>-hosp_type.
  ENDIF.

ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: no, it is not common. Isn't it simpler just post the code than describe it in words?

Comment: @Suncatcher hey sorry, I edited the post with the relevant code now.

Comment: `the read fails a lot of time even if it has same key in both tables` maybe there is just no matched records. How these tables are declared? give data samples from both

Comment: @Suncatcher I am checking manually in the tables and see that there are a matching records,
 also when removing the "binary search" addition, it finds these records.
lt_cov_entry[] is inline declared in a SELECT
t_patient_list[] is declared as exporting table in the function and it has ABAP Dictionary structure.

Comment: I tried you code with tables declared like `STANDARD TABLE OF kna1 WITH NON-UNIQUE KEY kunnr.` and it works

Comment: Please post a [reproducible standalone code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise it's impossible to tell what goes wrong.

Comment: I think I got the problem, I read from t_patient_list[] and if its not successful I append a line to this table, which breaks the sorting and then thats why binary search won't work

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I downvote the question because it's not useful for future visitors the way it's currently written. Eventually you may either generalize ("binary search doesn't work") or [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are appending to the table while you are reading it. After you append something, it might no longer be sorted, so `BINARY SEARCH` can no longer be expected to work reliably.

**Possible workaround:**

When the definition of the table `t_patient_list` is under your control, then add a secondary sorted table key to its declaration:

```
DATA t_patient_list TYPE TABLE OF patients 
                         WITH NON-UNIQUE SORTED KEY key_kunnr COMPONENTS kunnr.
```

(you might use an even faster `UNIQUE HASHED KEY` when you can guarantee that `kunnr` includes only unique values)

Then explicitly use that key when searching:

```
READ TABLE t_patient_list[]
    ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_patient_list>)
    WITH TABLE KEY key_kunnr COMPONENTS kunnr = <ls_cov_entry>-kunnr.
```

(The addition `BINARY SEARCH` isn't required here because using a sorted key implies binary search).

Secondary keys are updated whenever the table is changed, so you can rely on them staying consistent.

**More hackish workaround**

When the definition of the table `t_patient_list` is **not** under your control, then you have to re-sort the table after changing it:

```
IF sy-subrc <> 0.
    CLEAR ls_patient_record.
    MOVE-CORRESPONDING <ls_cov_entry> TO ls_patient_record.
    APPEND ls_patient_record TO t_patient_list[].
    SORT t_patient_list[].
ELSE.
```

But you might want to measure if the performance penalty of sorting it after every append isn't more than you save by using `BINARY SEARCH`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detaild answer! Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Assaf When this answer answered your question, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark-icon next to it.

Comment: Do not ever do SORT in a LOOP, it is slower than just abandoning all sorting. The READ TABLE sets sy-tabix to the right position even if the value is not found. So use `INSERT ... INDEX sy-tabix` instead of th APPEND, and you it works great (and fast)

Comment: @András Please avoid using "do not ever do X" statements. Only a sith deals in absolutes. There are always edge cases where common wisdom is wrong. When you teach people that there are certain rules in software development they must not ever break, then you establish [cargo cults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: @András However, your idea in the latter part of your comment to use `INSERT...INDEX sy-tabix` to insert the record at the right position isn't bad. You might want to post that as a separate answer.

Comment: @Philipp, this is one of the few rules that I have not seen an exception for. Also, unfortunately it is not _common_ wisdom, I see this mistake quite often. But give me one good example for an exception, and I delete the comment.

Answer (score 2):

It does not work with `BINARY SEARCH` becuse the `APPEND` ruins the ordering. The best solution is to define `t_patient_list` as `SORTED` by `kunnr`. <sup>1</sup>

If you cannot do that, you should use `INSERT ... INDEX sy-tabix` instead of `APPEND`, as even a failed `READ TABLE` sets it to the right value:

```
SORT t_patient_list[] BY kunnr.

LOOP AT lt_cov_entry[] ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_cov_entry>).
  READ TABLE t_patient_list[]
      ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_patient_list>)
      WITH KEY kunnr = <ls_cov_entry>-kunnr
      BINARY SEARCH.

  IF sy-subrc <> 0.
    CLEAR ls_patient_record.
    MOVE-CORRESPONDING <ls_cov_entry> TO ls_patient_record.
    INSERT ls_patient_record INTO t_patient_list[] INDEX sy-tabix.
  ELSE.
    <fs_patient_list>-hosp_type = <ls_cov_entry>-hosp_type.
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```

---

1 ) If you can change it to SORTED, you still need to replace APPEND with INSERT, just without the INDEX part.